multi instruments musixflx not working on standalone
It is needed to compile a multi instruments musixflx using standalone. The basic code is as follow:
\documentclass[border=7pt,varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{musicography}
\usepackage{musixtex}
\input musixlyr
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\xdefinecolor{red-undar}{RGB}{179,35,79}
\begin{document}
\begin{music}
\font\A=phvb8t at 8pt% added for letter type.
\font\B=phvb8t at 9pt% added for letter type.
\parindent10mm
\sepbarrules
%\smallmusicsize
\instrumentnumber{2}
\setclef16
\setclef{2}{\treble}
\setname2{Voz}
\setname1{Piano}
\setstaffs12
\setstaffs21
%\nobarnumbers
%\nostartrule
\def\writebarno{\A\the\barno}
%\renewcommand*\writebarno{\textit{\the\barno}}%
\scale{0.03}%
\startbarno=13%
\startpiece%\addspace{0.3\afterruleskip}% 
\notes\ibu0J1\zq{C}\qb0{J}|\ds&\qp\en%
\notes\ds|\zqu{ce}\cu{g}&\en%
\notes\tbu0\zq{L}\qb0{N}|\ds&\ds\en%
\notes\ds|\zqu{ce}\cu{g}&\ds\en%
\notes\slur{F}{G}d1\ibu0F1\qb0{^F}|\ds&\cup{g}\en%
\notes\tbu0\qb0{G}|\ds&\ccu{g}\en\bar%
\notes\ibu1H1\qb1{`G}|\ds&\isluru0m\ql{m}\en%
\notes\ds|\ibu0g{-1}\zqu{b}\qu{g}&\hqsk\en%
\notes\tbu1\qb1{G}|\tbu0\zqu{d}\qb0{f}&\tslur0k\cl{k}\en%
\notes\ds|\zqu{b}\qu{g}&\qp\en%
\notes\islurd0B\ibu2C1\qb2{B}|\hqsk&\hqsk\en%
\notes\tslur0D\tbu2\qb2{D}|\ds&\ds\en\bar%
\notes\ibu1H1\qb1{`G}|\ds&\isluru0m\ql{m}\en%
\notes\ds|\ibu0g{-1}\zqu{b}\qu{g}&\hqsk\en%
\notes\tbu1\qb1{G}|\tbu0\zqu{d}\qb0{f}&\tslur0k\cl{k}\en%
\notes\ds|\zqu{b}\qu{g}&\qp\en%
\notes\islurd0B\ibu2C1\qb2{B}|\hqsk&\hqsk\en%
\notes\tslur0D\tbu2\qb2{D}|\ds&\ds\en%\bar%
%\alaligne%
\setdoubleBAR%
\nolyr%
\lyricsoff%
\endpiece
\end{music}
\end{document}

The current output is as follow:


The problem of the broken result in standalone is because you are not running musixflx in the .tex archive after the first compilation. If this program is not run, there is no .mx2 file and the spacings will be wrong. Furthermore, you are scaling the note spaces to be 3% of the original size, so you need to change the scale value (I use 1 here in \scale)
\documentclass[border=7pt,varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{musicography}
\usepackage{musixtex}
\input musixlyr
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\xdefinecolor{red-undar}{RGB}{179,35,79}
\begin{document}
\begin{music}
\font\A=phvb8t at 8pt% added for letter type.
\font\B=phvb8t at 9pt% added for letter type.
\parindent10mm
\sepbarrules
%\smallmusicsize
\instrumentnumber{2}
\setclef16
\setclef{2}{\treble}
\setname2{Voz}
\setname1{Piano}
\setstaffs12
\setstaffs21
%\nobarnumbers
%\nostartrule
\def\writebarno{\A\the\barno}
%\renewcommand*\writebarno{\textit{\the\barno}}%
\scale{1}%
\startbarno=13%
\startpiece%\addspace{0.3\afterruleskip}% 
\notes\ibu0J1\zq{C}\qb0{J}|\ds&\qp\en%
\notes\ds|\zqu{ce}\cu{g}&\en%
\notes\tbu0\zq{L}\qb0{N}|\ds&\ds\en%
\notes\ds|\zqu{ce}\cu{g}&\ds\en%
\notes\slur{F}{G}d1\ibu0F1\qb0{^F}|\ds&\cup{g}\en%
\notes\tbu0\qb0{G}|\ds&\ccu{g}\en\bar%
\notes\ibu1H1\qb1{`G}|\ds&\isluru0m\ql{m}\en%
\notes\ds|\ibu0g{-1}\zqu{b}\qu{g}&\hqsk\en%
\notes\tbu1\qb1{G}|\tbu0\zqu{d}\qb0{f}&\tslur0k\cl{k}\en%
\notes\ds|\zqu{b}\qu{g}&\qp\en%
\notes\islurd0B\ibu2C1\qb2{B}|\hqsk&\hqsk\en%
\notes\tslur0D\tbu2\qb2{D}|\ds&\ds\en\bar%
\notes\ibu1H1\qb1{`G}|\ds&\isluru0m\ql{m}\en%
\notes\ds|\ibu0g{-1}\zqu{b}\qu{g}&\hqsk\en%
\notes\tbu1\qb1{G}|\tbu0\zqu{d}\qb0{f}&\tslur0k\cl{k}\en%
\notes\ds|\zqu{b}\qu{g}&\qp\en%
\notes\islurd0B\ibu2C1\qb2{B}|\hqsk&\hqsk\en%
\notes\tslur0D\tbu2\qb2{D}|\ds&\ds\en%\bar%
%\alaligne%
\setdoubleBAR%
\nolyr%
\lyricsoff%
\endpiece
\end{music}
\end{document}



Also mention that is needed to delete the previos compiled files (mx1 and mx2) before running the musixflx.
